# Remove/Delete method in Spring Data Rest

Tags: angularjs, spring-data-rest

how I can remove an entity with Spring Data Rest?

This is my repository:

```
package br.com.qrbibliokode.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

import br.com.qrbibliokode.entities.LivroEntity;

    @RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "livro", path = "livro")
    public interface LivroRepository extends CrudRepository<LivroEntity, Long> {

        LivroEntity findById(@Param("id") Long id);

        LivroEntity findByTitulo(@Param("titulo") String titulo);

        @Override
        public void delete(Long id);

        @Override
        public void delete(LivroEntity id);

    }
```

This is the server: http://felansu.sytes.net:8080/qr-bibliokode-ws/livro/

I try send the delete request (Whit Advanced Rest Client chrome-extension), but this is the return:

```
Status
403 Forbidden Show explanation Loading time: 41
Request headers 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36
Origin: chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo
Content-Type: application/json 
Accept: */*
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,ca;q=0.2,es;q=0.2
Cookie: archiva_login=%7B%22username%22%3A%22admin%22%2C%22password%22%3Anull%2C%22confirmPassword%22%3Anull%2C%22fullName%22%3A%22the%20administrator%22%2C%22email%22%3A%22gaferran%40gmail.com%22%2C%22permanent%22%3Afalse%2C%22validated%22%3Atrue%2C%22timestampAccountCreation%22%3Anull%2C%22timestampLastLogin%22%3Anull%2C%22timestampLastPasswordChange%22%3Anull%2C%22locked%22%3Afalse%2C%22passwordChangeRequired%22%3Afalse%2C%22assignedRoles%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22modified%22%3Afalse%2C%22readOnly%22%3Afalse%2C%22userManagerId%22%3Anull%2C%22rememberme%22%3Afalse%2C%22logged%22%3Afalse%7D; hudson_auto_refresh=true; __utma=269169510.1818243347.1410754939.1414082251.1414613247.11; __utmz=269169510.1410754939.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); auth_token=013273b46bafe62d0206136c3bc45eb62bd04d58
Response headers 
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 
Content-Type: text/plain 
Transfer-Encoding: chunked 
Date: Fri, 31 Oct 2014 20:36:35 GMT
```

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you are not authorized to do it. [Error code 403](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403)

Comment: Take a look at your `archiva_login`.

Answer (score 0):

This fix my problem.

I create the LivroController with @RestController annotation.

```
@RestController
public class LivroController {

@Autowired
LivroRepository livroRepository;

@RequestMapping(value = "/livroInserir", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody LivroEntity inserir(@RequestBody LivroEntity livro) {
    return livroRepository.save(livro);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/livroDeletarById", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public @ResponseBody void deletarById(@RequestParam(value="id") Long id) {
    livroRepository.delete(livroRepository.findById(id));
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/livroDeletarByTitulo", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public @ResponseBody void deletarByTitulo(@RequestParam(value="titulo") String titulo) {
    livroRepository.delete(livroRepository.findByTitulo(titulo));
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/livroProcurarById", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public LivroEntity procurarById(@RequestParam(value="id") Long id) {
    return livroRepository.findById(id);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/livroProcurarByTitulo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public LivroEntity procurarByTitulo(@RequestParam(value="titulo") String titulo) {
    return livroRepository.findByTitulo(titulo);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/livroListarTodos", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ArrayList<LivroEntity> listarTodos() {
    return (ArrayList<LivroEntity>) livroRepository.findAll();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/livroAtualizar", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = "application/json")
public LivroEntity atualizar(@RequestBody LivroEntity livro) {
    LivroEntity editado = livroRepository.findOne(livro.getId());
    editado.setTitulo(livro.getTitulo());
    return livroRepository.save(editado);
}
```

and use this syntax:

> Inserir livro via Post:
>   http:// localhost:8080/qr-bibliokode-ws/inserir
>   {"id":"1", "titulo":"Nome do livro"}

---

> Deletar por id via DELETE
>   http:// localhost:8080/qr-bibliokode-ws/livroDeletarById?id=1

---

> Deletar por titulo via DELETE
>   http:// localhost:8080/qr-bibliokode-ws/livroDeletarByTitulo?titulo=John

---

> Procurar por id via GET
>   http:// localhost:8080/qr-bibliokode-ws/livroProcurarById?id=1

---

> Procurar por titulo via GET
>   http:// localhost:8080/qr-bibliokode-ws/livroProcurarByTitulo?titulo=Johns

---

> Listar todos os livros via GET
>   http:// localhost:8080/qr-bibliokode-ws/livroListarTodos

---

> Atualizar livro via PUT
>   http:// localhost:8080/qr-bibliokode-ws/livroAtualizar
>   {"id":"1","titulo":"Novo titulo"}